# Update column in query as long as one of its members has a specific record

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i update status column in below query to status 1 as long as one of its members appear with status 1.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT 'A' CODE, 1 STATUS , 'Z' DESCRIPTION, '' MODIFIED FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A' CODE, 1 STATUS , 'W', '' MODIFIED  FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'A' CODE, 0 STATUS , 'F', '' MODIFIED  FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B' CODE, 0 STATUS , 'V', '' MODIFIED  FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B' CODE, 0 STATUS , 'D', '' MODIFIED  FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C' CODE, 1 STATUS , 'S', '' MODIFIED  FROM dual 
)

CODE|STATUS|DESCRIPTION|MODIFIED|
----|------|-----------|--------|
A   |     1|Z          |        |
A   |     1|W          |        |
A   |     0|F          |        |
B   |     0|V          |        |
B   |     0|D          |        |
C   |     1|S          |        |
```

Final result should be like below: since there is/are records for `CODE A` with `STATUS 1`

```
CODE|STATUS|DESCRIPTION|MODIFIED|
----|------|-----------|--------|
A   |     1|Z          |        |
A   |     1|W          |        |
A   |     1|F          |YES     |
B   |     0|V          |        |
B   |     0|D          |        |
C   |     1|S          |        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an analytic function for aggregation as returning the value grouped by `code`, and compare the current and modified values of `status` by using `DECODE()` such as

```
SELECT code,
       status,
       description,
       DECODE(status, status_old, '', 'YES') AS modified
  FROM (SELECT code,
               status AS status_old,
               MAX(status) OVER(PARTITION BY code) AS status,
               description,
               modified
          FROM t)
```

presumingly status has only two kind of values `1` and `0`

Comment: Yes it will only have 2 kinds of value

Comment: Works simple easy up to there, How do you modify the column `MODIFIED` ?

Comment: Yes sir ,`YES` if modified else `null`

Comment: That now is perfect